# How to use algebraic formula as an argument in an R function

Tags: r, function, eval, quote

I have a long list of different formulations for atmospheric vapor pressure.  I would like to make evaluation of these easier by writing a function that uses the formula as an argument, and finds a solution with the optimization function.  The code without a function looks like this (as an example):

```
  es <- function(ta){6.1121 * exp(((18.678 - ta/234.5) * ta)/(ta + 257.14)) * 100}
  ea <- es(ta) * rh/100
  result <- optimize(function(ta){abs(es - es(ta))}, c(-100,100), tol = 0.00001)$minimum
```

The formula inside the brackets in the "es" function is what I want to be used as an argument.  Some code I've tried looks like this:

```
formula <- '6.1121 * exp(((18.678 - ta/234.5) * ta)/(ta + 257.14)) * 100'

iterative_Td <- function(formula, ta, rh){
  es <- function(ta){
    substitute(formula)}

    ea <- es(ta) * rh/100

    return(optimize(function(ta){abs(ea - es(ta))}, c(-100,100), tol = 0.00001)$minimum)}
```

How do I reference the formula in the iterative_Td function to make this work?  I've tried various configurations of quote, eval, and substitute. None of them work.  Thank you.

EDIT: to test, a value of 20 for ta and 50 for rh is good.  You should get a Td value of 9.2506.

Comment: Why not just pass the function itself?

Comment: Because I would need 30+ functions, one for each equation.

Comment: Not necessarily.  It would depend on how the various candidate `es` functions differed.  Which is something you've not explained.  If, for example, they differ only in the coefficients of the various terms, then your statement is not true.  Other differences would provide different opportunities for simplification.  In any case, it would seem you have to do *something* 30+ times in order to define your 30+ equations....

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution as follows:

```
formula <- '6.1121 * exp(((18.678 - ta/234.5) * ta)/(ta + 257.14)) * 100'

ta = c(20,5,-10)
rh = c(50,40,70)

iterative_Td <- function(formula, ta, rh){
  es <- function(ta){
    parse(text = formula)}

  Td_array <- rep(NA,length(ta))
  ea <- eval(es(ta)) * rh/100

  for (i in 1:length(ea)){
    Td_array[i] = optimize(function(ta){abs(ea[i] - 
        eval(es(ta[i])))}, c(-100,100), tol = 0.00001)$minimum}

  return(Td_array)}

> iterative_Td(formula,ta,rh)
[1]   9.270961  -7.478382 -14.430393
```

Comment: Suggest you use: `ta = c(20,5,-10)
rh = c(50,40,70)

iterative_Td <- function(formula, ta, rh){
  es <- function(ta) {};
  body(es) <- parse(text = formula);

  ea <- es(ta) * rh/100;

  sapply(ea, \(ea) optimize(\(ta)abs(ea - es(ta)), c(-100, 100), tol = 0.00001)$minimum);
}; 

iterative_Td(formula,ta,rh)`